# Parse.com _User relation to _User

Tags: rest, associations, parse-platform, relationship

I have an array field called "friends" on my _User table that has pointers to other users in the _User table. If I were to make a REST GET on _Users, what query would give me all the friends for a given user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation on [REST API, Queries, Relational Queries](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-relational).

Basically you just need to add an `include=friends` to the url.

Comment: This is really weird – I've had very unreliable results with include and includeKey...sometimes include works and sometimes includeKey works... https://www.parse.com/questions/help-with-a-simple-relational-query led me to believe that includeKey was the correct param to use, but then after working for a while, includeKey started failing in that only the first record in that array would be turned into an object – the others would be pointers..Have you had issues with this? Is there something I should look into to make it more reliable? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use the REST API myself, my main focus is on the JavaScript API.